# ASP.NET ModalPopupExtender not rendering correctly

Tags: asp.net-ajax, rendering, modalpopupextender

I have a fairly straight forward screen that contains two modal popups. The first confirms a delete type operation and the other allows you to edit form details.

As soon as you open either for the popups they appear like they should but do not go away. At the bottom of the page they are rendered by asp.net with the exact same markup.

I am not sure why this happens. Any help would be appreciated

Comment: It seems that removing one of them makes it work. This will not work for my page so I still need to find a solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a potential work around that should be okay. The extra set of modal popups were rendered outside the form and so using CSS it was very easy to hide the unwanted elements. This is not ideal but it worked well enough.

Example:

```
form #modal { display: block; }
#modal { display: none; }
```

EDIT: Follow up

We have not seen this problem on all pages that have multiple modals which makes me think it is some other factor. Since then we have upgraded to .NET 3.5 and this may not be an issue using the latest versions of the toolkit.